# videos dont play in Epiphany

Tags: release-juno, epiphany

I have Juno installed and if I try to play a Video in Epiphany it is just red and grey. if I play the same video in Chromium it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad as this worked for me.